# Unable to host angular 2 sample in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I have done all the installation and my angular 2 app prod build is ready. Dist folder is created in it.

Once I do firebase init it is asking me to host the project once I choose my project listed, its saying 'Firebase initialization complete!' but its not asking which folder to choose and many more options.

Later If I run "firebase deploy" I am getting "Error: An unexpected error has occurred." what is the problem. Please suggest me

Comment: Try another init

Comment: Tried several times

Answer (score 0):

I just need to update my firebase.json like below

```
{
  "hosting": {
  "public": "dist",
  "rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
}
}
```